# emacs, #ifdef macro color change, and indent

Tags: emacs, syntax-highlighting, font-lock

I want my emacs to change code color to gray if the macro undefined, and also, in the case of #ifdef #else, a proper indent is needed too.

```
#define MY_MACRO
#ifdef MY_MACRO
int foo = 0;//proper indent, normal color
#else
int bar = 0;//proper indent, and gray color
```

Answer (score 2):

Emacs has a [`hide-ifdef-mode`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HideIfDef).

> In hide-ifdef-mode, code within #ifdef constructs that the C
>   preprocessor would eliminate may be hidden from view.

It can be activated via `M-x hide-ifdef-mode`. For a basic usage, use the function `hide-ifdefs` (default shortcut `C-c @ h`).
`

```
#define MY_MACRO
#ifdef MY_MACRO
int foo = 0;//proper indent, normal color
#else...
#endif
```

To revert the effects, use the function `show-ifdefs` (default shortcut `C-c @ s`):

```
#define MY_MACRO
#ifdef MY_MACRO
int foo = 0;//proper indent, normal color
#else
int bar = 0;//proper indent, and gray color
#endif
```

Comment: thanks@Lud, this is a solution to tell whether the MACRO is defined, but not what i want. i think color change would be a better choice, because i can see what is under UNDEFINED conveniently without 'show-ifdefs' cmd(although it is convenient too).so i'll let the thread open, and wait for my COLOR CHANGE SOLUTION.